# How to apply changes to working directory from local git repo?

Tags: git

I have a repo on main web-server and a local git repo. So then I change some files on local machine, I commit it to local repo and then push to remote repo on the web-server. But files in work-directory on web-server does not change. Now I use a command "git reset --hard" but I think it is not right. So how to apply changed from local repo to working directory?

Comment: Are you pushing changes in a detached head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good fature in GIT v.2.3.0+ - push-to-deploy.

So you need just config git:
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git push`, only the repository in remote will be changed, with remote work tree unchanged, that is why usually a remote repository was created by `git init --bare`.

If you want to update remote work tree by `git push`, you should write a post-receive hook to do it.

Comment: you are right. But if I create a bare repo, will it updates if I change some files in working directory?

Comment: @DmitryMorozov, if you create a bare repo, there are not working directory accompanied with repository. if you want to deploy your code on remote server, you can try `Push to Deploy`, which is a new feature introduced in git v.2.3.0

Comment: it is not a bare repo

Answer (score 0):

cd into the .git/hooks directory and create a file called “post-receive”. Copy the code below into the file:

## !/bin/bash

GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/your/htdocs/direcotry git checkout -f

make sure that this code is executable by running
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive